# Autogeneration of readonly Swift protocol exposing @Published properties

Tags: swift, protocols, combine

I'm currently working on a refactor where write access to model objects is restricted.  Model objects are reference types with @Published properties:

```
public final class Model {
  public enum State { /* Some cases here. */ }
  @Published public var state: State
}
```

Let's say that I want a view model that returns a string to be observed by the UI layer.  I'm using a protocol to expose readonly access to the view model, and a concrete implementation to support it:

```
public protocol ViewModelAPI {
  var stringPublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never> { get }
}

private struct ViewModel: ViewModelAPI {
  public let stringPublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never>
  init(model: Model) {
    stringPublisher =
      model.$state
      .map { /* Convert Model.State to string to display. */ }
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}

public final class StateStringView: UIView {
  init(viewModel: ViewModelAPI) { 
    /* Subscribe to `viewModel` to observe new String to display. */
  }
}
```

Generally, this approach works pretty well, in that it prevents the UI layer from having direct Model dependencies.  However, the ViewModel implementation has access to the settable `Model.state` property even though it only ever reads the property and never sets it.

Ideally, I'd like an easy way to create a protocol from an existing model object, such that we convert any `@Published` property into an `AnyPublisher` allowing readonly access.  I think creating a protocol by hand is appropriate for ViewModel APIs since it's tailored to specifically the data used by a single UI feature.  However, creating explicit observable protocols for all Model objects seems like a lot of overhead since it would require updating the protocol whenever the Model is updated.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to generate a protocol such that we could inspect a class and extract all of the `@Published` properties?  Would dynamic member lookup be a possible solution here?  Or would I just need to use a script to generate protocols that accomplish this?

Comment: Can't you just declare your model properties as `@Published public private(set) var state: State`?  Then nobody, not even the view model, would have write access to the model properties.

Comment: View Models only need read access to the models, but there are other classes that need to update properties on model objects.  So that service class would use a different protocol that allows model modification, while the VM would just access the readonly protocol.